# Move Multiple Source Files Into Single File

Tags: coldfusion

I need to take hundreds of files of source code and move them into a single file (for patent purposes).  All the source includes CSS, JS, HTML, and the Model Glue 2.0 framework.

I could somewhat easily construct a series of **cfdirectory** loops and **cffile read/write** actions to have everything read into a single, monstrous file. However, that seems inefficient and taxing on the server's resources (this is off a production box of ours)

Before I go down this route, are there any other solutions to this that are more automated?

**Edit**: It cannot be in a compressed format like zip, war, etcetera. It has to be in txt, pdf, etc.

Comment: Could you just create an archive (like ZIP) file?

Comment: or a deployable war file?

Comment: I cannot create a zip, war, or any other compressed file. It has to be in txt, pdf, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Any solution that aggregates all the files together is going to be doing the same thing: traversing a dir tree, reading the files, then [processing them somehow: in your case just stitching them together in a PDF etc].

If you're worried about processing overhead of doing this on files on your prod server, then *copy them off your prod server first*.

And I would just do this via the mechanism you describe in your second para.  The only thing I'm cautious about is your use of plural in "cfdirectory loopS". You'd only need one... `<cfdirectory>` has a `recurse` option, which means you can probably just get away with the one `<cfdirectory>` call, and one loop (and not much processing overhead).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use CF to do this, there are other tools available.

If you're just looking to concat each file into one giant file you can use DOS (assuming you're on a windows box) or move it to your windows pc (assuming you're not using a Mac) and simply script a small batch file. [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/keyboard-ninja/keyboard-ninja-concatenate-multiple-text-files-in-windows/) has a tutorial.

or you could do something like `C:\[your CF folder]>type *.cfm >> merge.txt` like [here](http://tekcert.com/blog/2012/04/23/how-concatenate-multiple-text-files-one)